# Create YouTube Playlist using NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I am trying to create a youtube playlist by using a NodeJS server.  I have followed the NodeJS quickstart instructions for Oauth as seen at this link: https://github.com/youtube/api-samples/blob/master/javascript/nodejs-quickstart.js

From this link, I have also been able to access channel information by using the method below:

```
function getChannel(auth) {
  var service = google.youtube('v3');
  service.channels.list({
    auth: auth,
    part: 'snippet,contentDetails,statistics',
    forUsername: 'GoogleDevelopers'
  }, function(err, response) {
    if (err) {
      console.log('The API returned an error: ' + err);
      return;
    }
    var channels = response.items;
    if (channels.length == 0) {
      console.log('No channel found.');
    } else {
      console.log('This channel\'s ID is %s. Its title is \'%s\', and ' +
                  'it has %s views.',
                  channels[0].id,
                  channels[0].snippet.title,
                  channels[0].statistics.viewCount);
    }
  });
}
```

I am now attempting to create a playlist through my server, but the only reference to how to accomplish this is through this JavaScript link: https://github.com/youtube/api-samples/blob/master/javascript/playlist_updates.js

And I have added this method from the above code to the nodejs-quickstart.js to try to accomplish that:

```
function createPlaylist() {
  var request = gapi.client.youtube.playlists.insert({
    part: 'snippet,status',
    resource: {
      snippet: {
        title: 'Test Playlist',
        description: 'A private playlist created with the YouTube API'
      },
      status: {
        privacyStatus: 'private'
      }
    }
  });
  request.execute(function(response) {
    var result = response.result;
    if (result) {
      playlistId = result.id;
      $('#playlist-id').val(playlistId);
      $('#playlist-title').html(result.snippet.title);
      $('#playlist-description').html(result.snippet.description);
    } else {
      $('#status').html('Could not create playlist');
    }
  });
}
```

I am having trouble translating this over to the NodeJS example, since there is no auth happening in the JS method, and since "gapi" and "client" don't exist/aren't mentioned in the nodeJS quickstart example.  Could someone help with translating this JS method over to nodeJS?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to use pure Nodejs, you should use [google api nodejs client](https://github.com/google/google-api-nodejs-client) and use this [sample usage](https://github.com/google/google-api-nodejs-client/blob/master/samples/youtube/playlist.js#L46) then follow the [documentation to insert playlist](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlists/insert)

And of course you will need [authentication process too](https://github.com/google/google-api-nodejs-client#generating-an-authentication-url)

Before starting the whole progress, make sure you have [installed google apis](https://github.com/google/google-api-nodejs-client#installation) into the project folder through the Console/SSH

**Sample**

*Console:* `npm install googleapis lien --save`

[Activate your Youtube Data API](https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/youtube.googleapis.com/overview)

```
var google = require('googleapis');
var Lien = require("lien");
var OAuth2 = google.auth.OAuth2;

var server = new Lien({
    host: "localhost"
  , port: 5000
});

var oauth2Client = new OAuth2(
  'YOUR_CLIENT_ID',
  'YOUR_CLIENT_SECRET',
  'http://localhost:5000/oauthcallback'
);

var scopes = [
  'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube'
];

var youtube = google.youtube({
  version: 'v3',
  auth: oauth2Client
});

server.addPage("/", lien => {
    var url = oauth2Client.generateAuthUrl({
        access_type: "offline",
        scope: scopes
    });
    lien.end("<a href='"+url+"'>Authenticate yourself</a>");
})

server.addPage("/oauthcallback", lien => {
    console.log("Code obtained: " + lien.query.code);
    oauth2Client.getToken(lien.query.code, (err, tokens) => {
        if(err){
            return console.log(err);
        }

        oauth2Client.setCredentials(tokens);
        youtube.playlists.insert({
            part: 'id,snippet',
            resource: {
                snippet: {
                    title:"Test",
                    description:"Description",
                }
            }
        }, function (err, data, response) {
            if (err) {
                lien.end('Error: ' + err);
            }
            else if (data) {
                lien.end(data);
            }
            if (response) {
                console.log('Status code: ' + response.statusCode);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

After you run your script, just go to http://localhost:5000/ through your favorite browser

Comment: your "documentation to insert playlist" link doesnt have an option for nodejs in the code samples that is my main problem

Comment: Look at the sample usage line 53, you will find `youtube.playlists.list`.. just change it to `youtube.playlists.insert` and learn the documentation

Comment: @Roger99 want's a clear comparison between **javascript** and **nodejs** snippet

Comment: @BharathvajGanesan: You provide the comparison, and I will provide the nodejs code

Comment: @BharathvajGanesan and StefansArya Is there any chance you could modify this code to show what adding a random video into this playlist while creating it would look like?

Answer (score 4):

For nodejs,

I suggest you to use these **nodeJS modules** developed by **Google**.

```
npm install googleapis --save
npm install google-auth-library --save
```

1. [googleapis](https://www.npmjs.com/package/googleapis)
2. [google-auth-library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/google-auth-library)

Consider the following **snippets** to **Create a Youtube playlist** in

**NodeJS**

```
googleapis.discover('youtube', 'v3').execute(function (err, client) {
    var request = client.youtube.playlists.insert(
       { part: 'snippet,status'},
       {
         snippet: {
           title: "hello",
           description: "description"
       },
       status: {
           privacyStatus: "private"
       }
   });
   request.withAuthClient(oauth2Client).execute(function (err, res) {...
});
```

**JavaScript**

```
function createPlaylist() {
   var request = gapi.client.youtube.playlists.insert({
      part: 'snippet,status',
      resource: {
         snippet: {
         title: 'Test Playlist',
         description: 'A private playlist created with the YouTube API'
         },
         status: {
            privacyStatus: 'private'
         }
      }
   });
   request.execute(function(response) {
      var result = response.result;
      ...
}
```

Comment: I have done all of this already, the link you posted is the same link I posted

Comment: Check this [Youtube's official Doc](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/quickstart/nodejs)

Comment: I have seen this page and I already have done all of it, what I am trying to accomplish is not detailed in the docs

Comment: @Roger99 I have edited the answer. Please Check, I have shown the comparison snippet. I hope this helps you.