# Add video to Youtube playlist NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I am currently working through the code to programmatically create a youtube playlist using a nodejs server that I received from [a previous question I had](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45554160/create-youtube-playlist-using-nodejs) and am using the working code below to do so:

```
var google = require('googleapis');
var Lien = require("lien");
var OAuth2 = google.auth.OAuth2;

var server = new Lien({
    host: "localhost"
  , port: 5000
});

var oauth2Client = new OAuth2(
  'YOUR_CLIENT_ID',
  'YOUR_CLIENT_SECRET',
  'http://localhost:5000/oauthcallback'
);

var scopes = [
  'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube'
];

var youtube = google.youtube({
  version: 'v3',
  auth: oauth2Client
});

server.addPage("/", lien => {
    var url = oauth2Client.generateAuthUrl({
        access_type: "offline",
        scope: scopes
    });
    lien.end("<a href='"+url+"'>Authenticate yourself</a>");
})

server.addPage("/oauthcallback", lien => {
    console.log("Code obtained: " + lien.query.code);
    oauth2Client.getToken(lien.query.code, (err, tokens) => {
        if(err){
            return console.log(err);
        }

        oauth2Client.setCredentials(tokens);
        youtube.playlists.insert({
            part: 'id,snippet',
            resource: {
                snippet: {
                    title:"Test",
                    description:"Description",
                }
            }
        }, function (err, data, response) {
            if (err) {
                lien.end('Error: ' + err);
            }
            else if (data) {
                lien.end(data);
            }
            if (response) {
                console.log('Status code: ' + response.statusCode);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

I am now moving on to the part of my project where I am in need of a way to add videos to this playlist once I have created it.  [The sample code that I am following along with](https://github.com/youtube/api-samples/blob/master/javascript/playlist_updates.js) is only written in JS and does not detail nodejs and I am therefore stuck on how to achieve this implementation with nodejs.  How could I create a method like this (received from the JS implementation from the link above):

```
function addToPlaylist(id, startPos, endPos) {
  var details = {
    videoId: id,
    kind: 'youtube#video'
  }
  if (startPos != undefined) {
    details['startAt'] = startPos;
  }
  if (endPos != undefined) {
    details['endAt'] = endPos;
  }
  var request = gapi.client.youtube.playlistItems.insert({
    part: 'snippet',
    resource: {
      snippet: {
        playlistId: playlistId,
        resourceId: details
      }
    }
  });
  request.execute(function(response) {
    $('#status').html('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(response.result) + '</pre>');
  });
}
```

in the NodeJS language using the implementation I have already started?

Comment: Did you succeed in your code ? I can't find out how to use Youtube api without OAuth token generation. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I get what you mean now.If you want to add a video on your playlist then  you can do that in Node using this.

```
  youtube.playlistItems.insert({
            part: 'id,snippet',
            resource: {
                snippet: {
                    playlistId:"YOUR_PLAYLIST_ID",
                    resourceId:{
                        videoId:"THE_VIDEO_ID_THAT_YOU_WANT_TO_ADD",
                        kind:"youtube#video"
                    }
                }
            }
        }, function (err, data, response) {
            if (err) {
                lien.end('Error: ' + err);
            }
            else if (data) {
                lien.end(data);
            }
            if (response) {
                console.log('Status code: ' + response.statusCode);
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to render the result as HTML, First you need to use a view engine like (jade or pug) then create a template then lastly render it along with the response.

Base on your example you can do it this way:

First Create a template( Im using Pug) Save it as results.pug

```
html
  head
    title= title
  body
    h1= title
    p=description

    img(src=thumbnails.medium.url)
```

Then update your code below:

```
var google = require('googleapis');
var Lien = require("lien");
var OAuth2 = google.auth.OAuth2;
var pug = require('pug')
var server = new Lien({
    host: "localhost"
  , port: 5000,
  views:{
    path:__dirname,
    name:'pug'
  }
});

var oauth2Client = new OAuth2(
  'YOUR_CLIENT_ID',
  'YOUR_CLIENT_SECRET',
  'http://localhost:5000/oauthcallback'
);

var scopes = [
  'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube'
];

var youtube = google.youtube({
  version: 'v3',
  auth: oauth2Client
});

server.addPage("/", lien => {
    var url = oauth2Client.generateAuthUrl({
        access_type: "offline",
        scope: scopes
    });
    lien.end("<a href='"+url+"'>Authenticate yourself</a>");
})

server.addPage("/oauthcallback", lien => {
    console.log("Code obtained: " + lien.query.code);
    oauth2Client.getToken(lien.query.code, (err, tokens) => {
        if(err){
            return console.log(err);
        }

        oauth2Client.setCredentials(tokens);
        youtube.playlists.insert({
            part: 'id,snippet',
            resource: {
                snippet: {
                    title:"Test",
                    description:"Description",
                }
            }
        }, function (err, data, response) {
            if (err) {
                lien.end('Error: ' + err);
            }
            else if (data) {
                //lien.end(data);
                lien.render('results',data.snippet)
            }
            if (response) {
                console.log('Status code: ' + response.statusCode);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

The things that I update on your code are:

```
var server = new Lien({
        host: "localhost"
      , port: 5000,
      views:{
        path:__dirname,
        name:'pug'
      }
    });
```

And

```
//lien.end(data);
lien.render('results',data.snippet)
```

Comment: I think you misunderstood the question or I misunderstood your answer, I am not trying to render anything in HTML, I am not making anything visual here.  All I want to know is how do you add a video to a playlist on youtube using nodejs